# HP Laptop 635 WIFI AR9285 don't work

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

I need help with my device HP635 and Aetheros AR9285.

OS : Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

**uname -a**

```
Linux sunzee-HP-635-Notebook-PC 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:06:14 UTC 2016 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A2**

```
   sunzee@sunzee-HP-635-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Atheros AR3011 Bluetooth 2.1+EDR  Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [103c:1461]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

**rfkill list all before i press F12**

```
    0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

**rfkill list all after F12**

```
sunzee@sunzee-HP-635-Notebook-PC:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
3: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```

If you know how i can beat this situation, please help :) It's very important for me, have access to wifi on this device :C

P.S My English is bad :C

Answer (score 0):

So, i solved a problem by myself.

```
sudo modprobe -r hp_wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo reboot
```

And load Bios settings to default.

Comment: I think loading bios defaults was enough in this case.